# Debugging TypeScript files outside wwwroot

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core

How should I debug TypeScript files in ASP.NET 5?
Suppose solution layout as on the following picture. Notice .ts Scripts are outside wwwroot folder and compiled .js file is getting there via Grunt task.
The task also creates .map file which references the original .ts files.

Note however that reference goes outside wwwroot (../Scripts/app.ts). This obviously doesn't work in a browser.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you copy your .ts in wwwroot ?

Comment: VS will complain about duplicate identifiers as same classes will be defined in 2 places.

Comment: also I don't think putting unnecessary files in wwwroot is the way we should work.

Comment: it's just for DEBUG, I'll remove on RELEASE

Comment: remember about my first comment. VS will complain about duplicate identifiers.

Comment: I think it conplains only if you open both file

Comment: complains with single file open only :(
I have created a workaround solution with a middleware that serves .ts files from outside wwwroot.
Still I would like to know how ASP.NET team envisions this should be done properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following action to one of my controllers, where `appEnvironment` is an `IApplicationEnvironment` injected into your controller:

```
#if DEBUG

[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
[Route("Scripts/{*pathInfo}", Order = 500)]
public IActionResult TestTypescript(string pathInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var path = appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath + "/Scripts/" + pathInfo;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path) && pathInfo.EndsWith(".ts"))
    {
        return File(path, "application/javascript");
    }
    else
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
}

#endif
```

Conveniently, the new web servers strip out the ../ (I'm assuming for security purposes), so you don't even have to worry about having them in the Route. (Note that you need to not have a `[RoutePrefix]` attribute on the controller itself for these paths to work.)

Comment: almost works. Had to replace:

var path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Scripts/" + pathInfo;

with:

var path = appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath + "/Scripts/" + pathInfo;

and add a constructor:
IApplicationEnvironment appEnvironment;
  public HomeController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnvironment)
  {
   this.appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
  }

Comment: That's a better way of doing it; I'll update the answer!

Comment: Won't work in ASP.NET core as File(path...) expects a virtual path and that can't be outside wwwroot. See @Ilya's answer for ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 14):

I still have exact the same problem in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. I solved it by using the following code snippet in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    { 
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(System.IO.Path.Combine(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath, "App")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/App"),
        });
    }
}
```

All my TypeScript-Files are under */App*

Comment: I find this answer the most clean solution under ASP.NET Core MVC development and that follows the required guidelines best.

Comment: This won't compile now after the release of ASP.Net Core 1.0, I have posted an updated code for this excellent idea below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40328737/1671558

Answer (score 6):

An update with ASP.Net Core release for a good stef's answer (that won't compile now):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Scripts")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/app"),
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to not quite work then `RequestPath` has a different name from the physical path, because Visual Studio is not aware of this path mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled across the same problem. Right now, with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, and I managed to overcome this issue by placing the tsconfig.json at the project root with the following content (note the exclude):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "bower_components",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

With this, you can have your task runner to copy *.ts files to the wwwroot and VS will not complain about duplicates. In fact, it will completely ignore all files beneath the paths in the exclude section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual studio 2015 RC and debugging for scripts outside of wwwroot folder works by default if I set internet explorer as the debug browser in visual studio.

This also gives you the opportunity to have breakpoints directly in the visual studio IDE.