# 'Duplicate identifier' error when compiling typescript definition files to wwwroot folder

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, grunt-ts

I have created a ASP.NET 5 project which I use mainly for a front-end typescript application.

I'm using grunt and grunt-ts to do the compilation.

I have a 'src' folder where all my typescript files are contained

grunt-ts compiles everything in the 'src' folder and combines this to a single js file which is then put in the wwwroot folder.
A typescript definition file is also generated and put in the wwwroot folder.

compiling with grunt/grunt-ts works flawlessly.

**The problem**:
When the definition file exist in the wwwroot folder, the visual studio IDE starts giving me lots of 'Duplicate identifier' errors.
This is of course because of the definition file.

Is there a way to make visual studio ignore the wwwroot folder (or any folder) for it's IDE/internal typescript compilation?

Comment: Seems to me that http://stackoverflow.com/q/29557837/195653 might have what you're looking for.

Comment: No, that covers a completley different topic

Comment: No, it's the same topic. Just using a controller to get the ts file content instead of copying the ts files into the wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add a `tsconfig.json` file to the root of your project which contains the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "bower_components",
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

The [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) file is responsible for
configuring TypeScript compilation.

- compilerOptions - TypeScript to JavaScript compilation options.

  - "noImplicitAny": true - Do not allow implicit any variables. Force them to be explicitly declared.
  - "noEmitOnError": true - Stop processing on error.
  - "removeComments": false - Do not remove comments.
  - "sourceMap": false - Do not create source map files (Leave this to the gulp plugin).
  - "module": "commonjs" - Use the Common JS modules.
  - "target": "es5" - Compile to ECMAScript 5.
- exclude - Exclude the bower_components, node_modules and wwwroot folders from being scanned for TypeScript
          (.ts) or TypeScript definition (.d.ts) files.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make visual studio ignore the wwwroot folder (or any folder) for it's IDE/internal typescript compilation ?

Exclude it from your project.

Comment: I don't see how this is possible in a ASP.NET 5 project since it follows the folder structure and also, if I exclude the wwwroot folder by deleting it or something it will affect my ability to debug

Comment: @basarat This currently isn't possible as simply as you're saying for VS2015: (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/30175235/195653).