# stop typescript compiler from creating .d.ts files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I want typescript to not create .d.ts files when compiling. This is because it causes a "duplicate Identifier" error on all class names. I have added this to the tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "outDir":"js/",
        "declaration": true
    },
  "exclude": [
    "bower_components",
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot" // this is the key line
  ]  
}
```

This is supposed to make it stop creating .d.ts files as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212149/3935156)

But I guess that is not the folder that I need to exclude because excluding it doesn't stop it creating .d.ts files for me. I am using visual studio code. What file do I need to exclude?

Comment: Could you clarify what definition cause this error?

Comment: @MaxFX any class name or variable name is in error because of the .d.ts file. when i delete the file manually the error goes away, but it recreated the file when I recompile

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If what you want is **not to generate** the `d.ts`files, then you need to **remove**:

```
declaration: true
```

from your compiler options in `tsconfig.json`

As specified in the [compiler options doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options#compiler-options)

> --declaration -d  Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file.