# Browser debugger cannot find source Typescript file (404) in ASP.NET core project

Tags: typescript

When my Firefox debugger (also Chrome) tries to find the source .ts file i'm getting the following error

```
Error while fetching an original source: request failed with status 404
Source URL: https://localhost:44308/TypeScript/DateTimeHelper.ts
```

The related source map points to the correct solution location

```
{"version":3,"file":"DateTimeHelper.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../TypeScript/DateTimeHelper.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":" ...
```

The path is correct for the VS solution but not for the web site. This may the issue but I'm not sure how to correct it.

I'm running VS 2017

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the TypeScript folder is outside the wwwroot folder. The answer was to map it so could be seen under the web site root folder

[Debugging TypeScript files outside wwwroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557837/debugging-typescript-files-outside-wwwroot/40328737#40328737)

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a .ts file directly, you need to reference a .js file that VS generated from your .ts file.

If VS isnt generating the .js file, try to use this help https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/18814/typescript-compilationgeneration-not-working.html

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The JavaScript is being generated correctly. It is the path back to the TypeScript file for debugging purposes that is causing the issue. I'm sure it relates to the way the JavaScript source mapping file links back to the TypeScript file in an ASP.NET Core environment

Comment: Oh, i really misunderstood your question, sorry. Do you have a local certificate? If not, the "https" path must be the problem.